# Can a player play after retirement?

Tags: rules, international-sports

If a player announced his retirement from international sports, Can he get back his retirement and play?

Who will decide on that(either the player or the country's sports authorities)?

Comment: Is your question focus in on Cricket only or in more a general one?

Comment: Are you asking about international matches?? or are you asking sport in general?? Looks like the focus of your question could be a little clear. What do you understand for international sports?

Comment: My focus is on cricket, but my question is on general.

Comment: There are some sports, particularly individual and Olympics sports, in which participants need to be declared to be retired or not in order to be eligible since all 'active' participants can be subjected to random drug tests but these cease when you retire. I think there are in some cases minimum periods of time you need to be declared 'active' before major events (like the Olympics) in order to comply with the drug testing rules. I have no references for this beyond anecdotes in athlete interviews, hence a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short **Yes**.

There are many examples of retired players who made a "comeback".

When a player decides to retire it is his or her personal decision, they can do whatever they decide to do.

I don't know anything about Cricket so I will refer to your question in general:

In case the player decides to do a "comeback" we can divide the "comeback" to 2 categories:

1. Personal sports (Like Tennis) - The player can register to play in the tournament like any other "unretired" player, e.g. [Kim Clijsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Clijsters) who announced her retirement from professional tennis on [2007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Clijsters#2007:_Retirement) and made a comeback on [2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Clijsters#2009:_Comeback) and even returned to 1st place in the WTA rankings.
2. Team sports (Like Basketball) - The player can announce a "comeback" and will need to find a team that will want him, or that his international team will called him up to play like every other Free Player. The best example is [Michael Jordan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jordan) who retired 3 times! 2 from Basketball and 1 from Baseball.

You can read about other athletes who made a comeback at the following [discussion](http://forum.santabanta.com/showthread.htm?277955-15-Athletes-Who-Retired-and-Came-Back).

Referring to your focusing on Cricket and international performance I found this player: [Brad Hogg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brad_Hogg) as an example to a player who retire from international cricket on 27 February 2008 and made his comeback 2 years later On 1 February 2012 representing Australia at the Sydney Olympic Stadium in a Twenty20 international against India.

Comment: Another great who made a comeback from retirement goes by the name Micheal Schumacher.
The best example in cricket would be Javed Miandad who made a comeback just to play the World Cup in 1996, thereby becoming the then only player to have played in all the World Cups.

Comment: Would like to add that Michael Jordan retired from basketball **three** times (1993, 1999, 2003)

Answer (score 0):

Yes in most professional sports a player can come out of retirement.  They would need picked up by a team and signed to a contract.  But there are many examples of players coming back Michael Jordan did it twice.